# Ionic 4 Karma code coverage generates HTML file with no data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, istanbul, karma-coverage

Running `ng test --code-coverage` in my Ionic project folder generates the coverage folder with all needed html/css/js files. The `lcov.info` file contains the test data - but the html files do not have the values in it.

One example row from the `index.html`:

```html
<tr>
    <td class="file high" data-value="src"><a href="src/index.html">src</a></td>
    <td data-value="" class="pic high"><div class="chart"><div class="cover-fill" style="width: 0%;"></div><div class="cover-empty" style="width:100%;"></div></div></td>
    <td data-value="" class="pct high">%</td>
    <td data-value="" class="abs high">/</td>
    <td data-value="" class="pct high">%</td>
    <td data-value="" class="abs high">/</td>
    <td data-value="" class="pct high">%</td>
    <td data-value="" class="abs high">/</td>
    <td data-value="" class="pct high">%</td>
    <td data-value="" class="abs high">/</td>
</tr>
```

This is the file in a browser:
[image: generated-html-file-in-browser]

It seems that the styling got the information from lcov data, because the colors match the data I get via terminal:

```sh
----------------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                                                |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                                           |    49.75 |    10.77 |    38.67 |    48.13 |                   |
 src                                                |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  polyfills.ts                                      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  test.ts                                           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  zone-flags.ts                                     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 src/app                                            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  app.component.ts                                  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 src/app/calendar                                   |    16.56 |        0 |     8.89 |    16.44 |                   |
  calendar.page.ts                                  |    16.56 |        0 |     8.89 |    16.44 |... 24,425,426,427 |
 src/app/calendar/assignment                        |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  assignment.component.ts                           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 src/app/calendar/resource                          |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  resource.component.ts                             |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 src/app/calendar/resource-selection                |       75 |      100 |       40 |    72.73 |                   |
  resource-selection.component.ts                   |       75 |      100 |       40 |    72.73 |          32,34,35 |
[...]
```

Here is my karma configuration:

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
  });
};
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The 'coverage' reporter does generate the full detailed report in text format, but not HTML. I get all blank fields like you.

Comment: @Alex.A Do you have a solution? It’s still not working for me.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @HugoB., What's your karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter version?

Comment: @AriLinn `"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1"`

Comment: @HugoB. I had the same issue with v. ~2.0.5, upgrading to ~2.0.6 solved the problem in my case. Can't advise anything useful, but as a last resort you may try and go through several versions to see if one of them would work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by handlebars lib. Regression was introduced in recent version. So, in order to fix this (as a workaround untill handlebars lib fixed) - you can either install working version of handlebars manually and add it to your `devDependencies` like so: `npm i -D handlebars@4.1.2` or change version of handlebars onto correct one in your `npm-shrinkwrap.json`/`package-lock.json` like so:

```
         "handlebars": {
-            "version": "4.7.3",
-            "integrity": "sha1-js4nl4Johs+AgtFyb/IdKgIlUO4=",
+            "version": "4.1.2",
+            "integrity": "sha512-nvfrjqvt9xQ8Z/w0ijewdD/vvWDTOweBUm96NTr66Wfvo1mJenBLwcYmPs3TIBP5ruzYGD7Hx/DaM9RmhroGPw==",
             "requires": {
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I was not able to generate the HTML representation of full code coverage results. However I was able to generate in text format as well as cobertura(Junit) for CI/CD integration.

My karma.conf.js:

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

[image: Part 3]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this does not answer or provide a solution to my question.

Comment: With cobertura XML you can feed that into many CI/CD frameworks to get code coverage results rendered into an HTML dashboard. It just isn't on the local machine.

Answer (score -1):

1. Delete `package-lock.json`.
2. `rm -rf node_modules`.
3. Run `npm install`.

Comment: Deleting package-lock.json is not necessary.